# Why can't I make this assignment in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

The code below returns a warning saying "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame". I checked the linked documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) but didn't quite understand what it meant. Could anyone explain why this is not allowed and how else I could do the assignment?

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"Tagname": ["xx","yy"], "Value": [1,3], "Min": [3, 3], "Max": [3,3]})
a.loc[1][2]=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.loc[1]` returns a new series. You then want to index into that series again and set a value. But you never assigned a name to `a.loc[1]` so the result gets lost.

Use `a.iloc[1, 2] = 2` or `a.loc[1, 'Min'] = 2`.

---

If you were using lists, your attempt would be equivalent to setting a value in a copy of an inner list. Demo:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2]]
>>> l[0].copy()[0] = 3
>>> l
[[1, 2]]
```

Comment: Ah okay. I was indexing in like I do with a list. Your way worked, thanks.